# <my:foo> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mycomponents, but no tag was defined for name: foo

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component, nested

I have a composite component named `<my:foo>` and I'm building another composite component named `<my:bar>`. But when I attempt to use `<my:foo>` inside the `<cc:implementation>` of `<my:bar>`, the following exception is been thrown:

> `<my:foo>` Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mycomponents, but no tag was defined for name: foo

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a bug which was introduced in Mojarra 2.1.8, continued in 2.1.9 and is fixed in 2.1.10. This bug causes that composite component's own XML namespace cannot be declared in a root XML element like `<ui:component>`/`<ui:composition>`/`<html>`/etc as follows:

```html
<ui:component 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mycomponents"
>
    <cc:interface>
        ...
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <my:foo />
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

This would result in the following exception when you attempt to nest `<my:foo>` inside the `<cc:implementation>`.

> `<my:foo>` Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mycomponents, but no tag was defined for name: foo

The current workaround, apart from downgrading to 2.1.7 and waiting for 2.1.10 to be released, is to move the XML namespace declaration into the `<cc:implementation>`.

```html
<ui:component 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
>
    <cc:interface>
        ...
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mycomponents">
        <my:foo />
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

#### See also:

- [Mojarra issue 2392](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2392)
- [Mojarra issue 2437](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2437)

Comment: Since when do you have to log in to view the Jira issues? I've been on those pages before without having to login?

Comment: @Louise: actually, that's new to me as well. Sorry, I have no affiliation with Mojarra JIRA, so I'm not sure about the reasons. I do however agree that the login requirement makes no sense.

Comment: Bummer. I do have the same problem but without even nesting components, so the above solution doesn't apply. Some comments on those issues described this version of the problem, but I didn't have the time last year to look into it. Now the only option to read up on them is to make an account ... yet another one ;)