# Mojarra JSF 2.1.9 exception while loading a page which has got composite component

Tags: java, jsf, mojarra

I am upgrading my Mojarra JSF 2.0 on my web app to the latest stable version of Mojarra JSF2.1.9 . The pages were loading ok with the earlier version of Mojarra. But with the new version I am getting the following error message while loading a JSF page which has got composite components.

```
 /faces/page.xhtml @8,62 Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components, but no tag was defined for name: webContent
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
```

I have a composite element 'webContent' defined within my web application at the location'/resources/components' and it used to work with the earlier version of Mojarra JSF. Any clue , why am I getting this crash.

Comment: `webContent` is not the same as `webComponent`. Is this the real code or just result of careless formulation of the question?

Comment: Hi BalusC, the 'webComponent' was a typo error and i have corrected it in the post to 'webContent'.

Comment: I have found the issue ... it seems JSF Composite components doesn't work well with Mojarra2.1.9 . My application worked fine with Mojarra 2.1.7 when I replaced Mojara 2.1.9 with an earlier version 2.1.7

Comment: possible duplicate of [<my:foo> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mycomponents, but no tag was defined for name: foo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898906/myfoo-tag-library-supports-namespace-http-java-sun-com-jsf-composite-mycom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what my real issue was and the correct soultion to the problem:

I am using Webspehere 7 server and it suppports only 'Java Servlet 2.5'.
The pre-requisite for all versions of JSF Mojarra from 2.1.1 onward need 'Java Servlet 3.0'.

Mojarra 2.0.9 is the most recent stable version which supports 'Java Servlet2.5'. When I used Mojarra 2.0.9 , I had no issues, everything worked well.

Thanks,
Joe