# JSF Composite component not working on Mojarra 2.1.9

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, websphere, mojarra

All gurus in the forum , I really need your help..

My issue :
My JSF Mojara based application has got composite components and life was good untill we upgraded to the latest version of Mojarra2.1.9 .The JSF Composite components on my application stopped working after the upgrade ...when the pages are requested, a crash occurs complianing that my component is not defined ...There no code changes done to the app . Any clue why would JSF composite component stop working with the latest Mojarra 2.1.9 ...

Comment: I have found the issue ... it seems JSF Composite components doesn't work well with Mojarra2.1.9 . My application worked fine with Mojarra 2.1.7 when I replaced Mojara 2.1.9 with an earlier version 2.1.7

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that composite component does not work in mojarra2.1.9. Composite components are an often used construct in JSF. You should also be more specific about what does your component look like, what is the exact exception, etc. It is also very important to paste the exact exception, in order to help developers with the same issue to find your question and the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [<my:foo> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mycomponents, but no tag was defined for name: foo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898906/myfoo-tag-library-supports-namespace-http-java-sun-com-jsf-composite-mycom)

Answer (score 2):

I have found what my real issue is and the correct soultion to the problem:

**Issue:**
I am using Webspehere 7 server and it suppports only 'Java Servlet 2.5'. All versions of JSF Mojarra from 2.1.1 onward need 'Java Servlet 3.0' to work.

While I was debugging , had no clue about what was causing the crash with composite components. Hence I was trying different versions of Mojarra to see if that will resolve the issue.  When I used Mojarra 2.1.7 system stopped giving me the composite component exception and as a result I misinterpretted that Mojarra 2.1.7 was the stable version that didn't have any issue. But soon I realised that there were other new issues introduced within the app(eg. Ajax stopped working etc..)

**Solution to issue:**
Mojarra 2.0.9 is the most recent stable version which supports 'Java Servlet 2.5'. When I used Mojarra 2.0.9 , everything works well.

Thanks, AJ