# "Tag not found" exception when first navigating to page

Tags: templates, jsf, composite-component

I encountered the following problem in our application: After each server restart or redeployment of the application the first attempt to navigate to one specific page will fail with an exception:

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /testing/target.xhtml @8,72 <ofc:testComp> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/of-components, but no tag was defined for name: testComp
```

I laboured a while to strip this down to a minimal version. In doing so I figured out the following:

The problem occurs when:

- The server has been restarted or the application redeployed
- One tries to navigate to a certain page through an `h:commandLink`
- The target page uses a composite component

The problem goes away when:

- one reaches the target page in some other way, e.g. through an `h:outputLink` or via URL
- ever after the target page has been successfully reached once

I ruled out all kinds of things (we're on Mojarra 2.1.7 and the target page does not nest components, so it's not this problem with [nested namespace declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10898906/840977)) and narrowed it down to the following "culprit":

The source page uses a template, which I simplified as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Testpage</title>        
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <ui:insert name="content"/>
        <ui:include src="some_other_content.xhtml" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

If I remove the `ui:include` everything works. Can somebody explain to me what is happening here? It seems to have something to do with initializing my component library after a server restart, but I don't get how the include in the template has to do with it. As far as I know this is the standard way to include some fixed content to a page? If this is not how it should be done, please let me know what other ways there are.

Thanks!

---

---

**Remaining code snippets for completeness** (no magic happening here):

**source_page.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition template="/testing/test_template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:outputLink value="target.xhtml">Outputlink to target</h:outputLink> <br />
        <h:commandLink value="Commandlink to target" action="target.xhtml" />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**target.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ofc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/of-components"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ofc:testComp content="This is a component for testing purposes" />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**testComp.xhtml**

```
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

     <cc:interface>
         <cc:attribute name="content" required="true" />
     </cc:interface>

     <cc:implementation>
         <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.content}" />
     </cc:implementation>
 </html>
```

And finally, **some_other_content.xhtml** is just a random Hello-World-Page.

Comment: Basically you're saying that your `<ofc:testComp>` is not working, isn't it? That's also what the error trace suggests. I've never worked with that kind of components, but be sure they are located in your *webapp/resources/of-components* path. That's what this related link says http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/composite-components-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: Basically, what I am saying is that the components work fine in nearly all cases. They are located in the right spot, found without error and displayed. The real application has been using them for ages now. It's only this one navigation scenario where something goes wrong.

Comment: To exclude one and other I'd give Mojarra 2.1.17 a try.

Comment: The [repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl) only lists versions up to 2.1.16. We'll check that out, but it might take a few days (the server config guy is a busy man ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took quite some time, but we finally managed to upgrade. We are now running Mojarra 2.1.21.

I re-enabled the include and tried to restore the original setup as best as I could. I did not get any errors. The code has changed in other places too, so I can't say with absolute certainty that this was the sole reason it works. However, the original problem was quite reproducible and the general setup is basically the same as before, so I'm pretty sure one of those many skipped Mojarra versions did the trick.