# JSF 2.1.13 custom component not found: Tag Library supports namespace: <namsepace> but no tag was defined for name: <compositecomponent>

Tags: java, jsf-2, composite-component, mojarra

## Problem

I am using `JSF 2.1.13` to create a prototype to demostrate the benefits of JSF over our current webapp built with `JSP` and `struts 1.1`.  I following code using works with `JSF 2.2.6`, but I had to down grade once I found out that Oracle Weblogic 12c doesn't support JSF 2.2 yet.  When running the code with 2.1.13 I receive the following error:

```
/pages/sites/tab-details.xhtml @27,90 <ccc:codedType> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/ccc, but no tag was defined for name: codedType
```

Googling only pointed me to a [bug about nested composite components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898906), but that isn't something I'm doing.

## Code

### Excerpt from `pom.xml`

```
<!-- JSF Dependencies -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.13</version>
</dependency>
```

### Composite Compontent: `webapp/WEB-INF/resources/ccc/codedType.xhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
  <cc:interface shortDescription="Renders a CodedType">
    <cc:attribute name="value" required="true"
      shortDescription="Instance of CodedType to be properly rendered"
      type="company.prototype.uireplacement.presenter.CodedType" />
    <cc:attribute name="includeCode"
      shortDescription="Whether or not the rendeder type should include the code"
      type="boolean" default="false"/>
  </cc:interface>

  <cc:implementation>
    <span id="#{cc.attrs.id}">#{cc.attrs.value.label}<ui:fragment rendered="#{cc.attrs.includeCode}"> (#{cc.attrs.value.code})</ui:fragment></span>
  </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

### Page using composite component: `webapp/pages/sites/tab-details.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:ccc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/ccc">

      <ccc:codedType value="#{siteControllerBean.selectedSite.type}" includeCode="true"/>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After more digging I found what caused my error. Note the location of my compontent: `webapp/WEB-INF/resources/ccc/codedType.xhtml`.  The appropriate location should be `webapp/resources/ccc/codedType.xhtml` (root vs `WEB-INF`).  In JSF 2.2, they allowed the location to be configurable and I had the following in my `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources</param-value>
</context-param>
```

which is why things worked in JSF 2.2.

The fix for my situation was to remove `javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY` since it isn't used in JSF 2.1 and move the resources to the root.

Answer (score -1):

I recently got this error:
Make sure you put your template at location src../META-INF/resources/myFolder
and refer it using  xmlns:tp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/myFolder">
This helped me resolve the issue.